# Spark - read text file, string off first X and last Y rows using monotonically_increasing_id

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to read in files from vendors, that can get potentially pretty big (multiple GB).  These files may have multiple header and footer rows I want to strip off.

Reading the file in is easy:

```
val rawData = spark.read
.format("csv")
.option("delimiter","|")
.option("mode","PERMISSIVE")
.schema(schema)
.load("/path/to/file.csv")
```

I can add a simple row number using monotonically_increasing_id:

```
val withRN = rawData.withColumn("aIndex",monotonically_increasing_id())
```

That seems to work fine.
I can easily use that to strip off header rows:

```
val noHeader = withRN.filter($"aIndex".geq(2))
```

but how can I strip off footer rows?
I was thinking about getting the max of the index column, and using that as a filter, but I can't make that work.

```
val MaxRN = withRN.agg(max($"aIndex")).first.toString
val noFooter = noHeader.filter($"aIndex".leq(MaxRN))
```

That returns no rows, because MaxRN is a string.
If I try to convert it to a long, that fails:

```
noHeader.filter($"aIndex".leq(MaxRN.toLong))
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[100000]"
```

How can I use that max value in a filter?
Is trying to use monotonically_increasing_id like this even a viable approach?  Is it really deterministic?

Comment: have you try noHeader.filter($"aIndex" < MaxRN.toLong)

Comment: Yep, that returns the same NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `first` will return a [Row](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.scala). To access the first element of the row you must do:

```scala
val MaxRN = withRN.agg(max($"aIndex")).first.getLong(0)
```

By converting the row to string you will get `[100000]` and of course this is not a valid `Long` that's why the casting is failing.